Is it possible to get inner text from html in NestJS
I send to my database a raw html. But I want to create a slug and to do that, I would prefer to use innerText instead of html. I wanted to do
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = data.description;

    let slug = slugify(div.innerText);

But NestJS throws an error. Is there any method that I could use to get somehow innerText from this raw html?

With Nextjs, the document object and its methods like createElement and innerText are specific to the browser environment and not available on the server side.
Why don't create a string ?
const newDiv = `<div>${data.description}</div>`
....

